# Layout issues with <video> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im having a layout issues with `<video>` element. The issue is that it overflows and adds a verticall scroll (at 1839px of width and above). At smaller resolutions it doesnt occur.I want everything to be aligned perfectly and fit in that `100vh` `.App` container and no scroll being added.

I made a simple reproduction. You have to open rendered solution in another page to see the missalignment of `.video-container` element. Once you open that you can see button does not fit in `100vh`.

code reproduction - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/optimistic-river-5r5gq4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A6%2C26

rendered solution in another page - https://5r5gq4.csb.app/

Comment: Can you share an image of the problem? I opened the rendered solution, and it seems to work just fine—no vertical overflow at all.

Comment: At 1839px (and above) of width there is being vertical scroll added and thats the issue. There shouldn't be any scroll added.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want everything to be aligned perfectly and fit in that `100vh` `.App` container and no scroll being added.*

`display: grid` can achieve this:

```js
const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="header">Header</header>
    <div className="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <main>
      <ReactPlayer
        className="player"
        controls
        height="100%"
        url="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        width="100%"
      />
    </main>
    <footer>
      <button>Test</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template: 'header header' auto 'sidebar main' 1fr 'sidebar footer' auto / 300px 1fr;
}

header {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  grid-area: header;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  align-self: stretch;
  position: relative;
}

main video {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.player {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0.3rem 3.5rem;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-player@2.13.0/dist/ReactPlayer.js'></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

- pay attention to the markup (DOM structure) changes, not only the CSS (`header`, `.sidebar`, `main` and `footer` are siblings inside `.App`)
- `header` and `footer` have no hard-coded heights, `main` and `.sidebar` adjust to the remaining space
- if you want the sidebar contents to remain accessible even when they need more than the available height, place `overflow-y: auto` on it.
- note I'm taking `.player` out of content flow and having it match its parent size (`inset: 0; position: absolute;`). This way, the parent `main` has no size constraints whatsoever from the `<video />`
- the hard-coded `300px` width of `.sidebar` might become a problem on mobiles. perhaps hide it and allow users to open it as overlay!? (I've added a basic demo to the sandbox linked below).
- the verbose syntax for `grid-template` would be:

```css
.App {
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidebar main" "sidebar footer";
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

---

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/xw8fsl).

Answer (score 0):

The layout can be fixed by over-riding the ReactPlayer CSS.
Adding the following class `.player` to your component & stylesheet should allow the video and button to always fit in the screen regardless of the width of the screen:

```js
//...
  <ReactPlayer
    className={"player"} // Add Class Name here
    controls
    url="..."
    width={"100%"}
    height={"calc(100% - 36px)"} /* Changed */
  />
  <button style={{ height: "36px" }}>Test</button> /* Added */
//...
```

```css
.video-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 2;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* Added */
}
.player {
    width: 100%; /* Changed */
    height: 100%; /* Changed */
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: Video should always be 100% widh, because there are empty spaces between video 
- sidebar and video - right edge of page, which start to appear for 1834px of width and above

Comment: The `flex: 1` would automatically maintain full width and height for `video player`. The video itself has a certain ratio so anytime it the width is too long you would see white space on left and right, or height is too long you would see space on top and bottom. If you want to the video to take full space regardless of it's ratio, then you need to add `object-fit: cover` to the `player` class.

Comment: But its not about a video that have white spaces on left and right. Inspect dev tools and target video element. You can see those white spaces are not coming from video element but from .video-container.

Comment: Yes, that is correct seems like it wasn't working. I have **updated the answer**, it does work now but I'm not sure what the use case is but the heights would have to be pre-determined to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the vertical scroll that you're talking about on codesandbox and on the pop-up live page, but I do see the two white columns on the left and right side of the video.

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.player > video {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

This is probably your best move because your video resolutions will not fit all screen resolutions. Using `object-fit: cover` will ensure that the image is always large enough to cover all of the available space in its parent container.

Alternatively, you can use, `object-fit: fill` **but** if you have a screen that is too tall or too wide, you'll notice that the video itself can get stretched or compressed. If you'd like to go in this route, you should think about adding [breakpoints](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp) for both height and width.

- [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-banzai-dp8zlq?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css)
- [Live Page](https://dp8zlq.csb.app/)